# Loading VertexShader removes all sprites?

Tags: xna, shader, xna-4.0

I have a problem when I load my Vertex Shader in my effect file in XNA 4.0.

So without this row under it will work exact as I want.

```
VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VertexShaderFunction();
```

So what have I done so far... Nothing really! :)

1. Load image and effect file.

   ```
   protected override void LoadContent()
   {
       spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

       myTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("textures\\fan");
       effect = Content.Load<Effect>("effects\\ashader");
   }
   ```
2. Draw the image on the screen.

   ```
   protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
   {
       GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

       // Draw the sprite.
       spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
       effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();
       spriteBatch.Draw(myTexture, spritePosition,Color.White);

       spriteBatch.End();

       base.Draw(gameTime);

   }
   ```
3. Shader

   ```
   float4x4 World;
   float4x4 View;
   float4x4 Projection;

   struct VertexShaderInput
   {
       float4 Position : POSITION0;
   };

   struct VertexShaderOutput
   {
       float4 Position : POSITION0;
   };

   VertexShaderOutput VertexShaderFunction(VertexShaderInput input)
   {
       VertexShaderOutput output;

       float4 worldPosition = mul(input.Position, World);
       float4 viewPosition = mul(worldPosition, View);
       output.Position = mul(viewPosition, Projection);

       return output;
   }

   float4 PixelShaderFunction(VertexShaderOutput input) : COLOR0
   {
       return float4(1, 0, 0, 1);
   }

   technique Technique1
   {
       pass Pass1
       {
           VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VertexShaderFunction();
           PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PixelShaderFunction();
       }
   }
   ```

This should draw a red square where the texture is positioned. It does this without the VertexShader loaded. But when loading it, no textures shown at all.

So what have i missed?

Comment: This might help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294176/apply-post-render-effect-to-spritebatch-in-xna

Comment: The spritebatch and effect just simply do not work that way. The above link suggests RenderTargets (which is what I suggest as well).